# Fabric8 / Minikube: Builds in Jenkins are failing due to authorization problems

Tags: authorization, fabric8, minikube

I wanted to learn more about Fabric8, however, it is not possible to build even a very simple project. I am running it locally on a Minikube cluster.

The setup is:

- Mac OS Sierra
- Minikube v0.18.0
- Fabric8 v0.4.122

So I have a simple Spring Boot application in the local Gogs repository. The builds are failing with this message:

```
/usr/bin/git checkout -f d8af29f8af7a498331a244d245fb321003ef110d
/usr/bin/git rev-list d8af29f8af7a498331a244d245fb321003ef110d # timeout=10
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClientException: An error has occurred.
at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClientException.launderThrowable(KubernetesClientException.java:57)
at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.utils.HttpClientUtils.createHttpClient(HttpClientUtils.java:153)
[...]
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1949)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:302)
```

So I took the ca.crt from Minikube (~/minikube/ca.crt) and added it (base64-encoded) to the jenkins-git-ssh secret which gets mounted in the Jenkins pod in /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount. The next build ended with this error:

```
/usr/bin/git checkout -f d8af29f8af7a498331a244d245fb321003ef110d
/usr/bin/git rev-list d8af29f8af7a498331a244d245fb321003ef110d # timeout=10
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClientException: Failure executing: GET at: https://kubernetes.default/. Message: Unauthorized
.
```

The same happens when I use apiserver.crt from Minikube.

When using ca.pem instead I get:

```
Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateException: Unable to initialize, java.io.IOException: extra data given to DerValue constructor
at sun.security.x509.X509CertImpl.<init>(X509CertImpl.java:198)
at sun.security.provider.X509Factory.engineGenerateCertificate(X509Factory.java:102)
```

I can access the Kubernetes API from the Jenkins pod only when adding both apiserver.crt and apiserver.key to the secret. Executing

```
curl -k --cert apiserver.crt --key apiserver.key https://kubernetes.default/.
```

is successful then - but the Jenkins build is still failing.

So Im a bit lost here. Does anybody have an idea how to continue?

Thanks and regards,
Daniel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we have a fix but it's not released yet.  Details can be found https://github.com/fabric8io/fabric8/issues/6829#issuecomment-301467664 which also describes a workaround.

TL;DR you can edit the jenkins service account and remove the following lines before restarting the jenkins master pod:

```
-secrets:       
 -- name: "jenkins-git-ssh"     
 -- name: "jenkins-master-ssh"      
 -- name: "jenkins-release-gpg"
```

Hope that helps.